# Odata V4 how to allow special character like lastname with single quote O'Keefe

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api2, odata

We have OData post to insert client first name and last name, but we have a problem with the last name with the single quotes like O'Keefe or O'Brien. whenever we have the last name with the single quote it will reject the data.just I want to ask how to enable OData to accept special character in web.config or Web API configuration?

Answer (score 0):

We found this GitHub issue  and it includes workaround 
[[Breaking Change] Exception deserializing open type properties that contain special characters like open bracket '[' or single quote ' in ODataV4-7.x](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/764)